# Trying JSON Encoding of Ajax function sending values

Tags: php, ajax, json

I am using a hidden field and appending values with the following function.

```
 $( "#invite_suggestion" ).autocomplete({
    source: BASEURL + 'index.php/search_contacts_suggestion/',
    select: function( event, ui )
    {

      $('#invite_id').val($('#invite_id').val()+ui.item.friend_id); 

    }
});
```

In the PHP side

```
$_POST['invite_id']=(isset($_POST['invite_id']))?json_encode(array($_POST['invite_id'])):json_encode(NULL);
```

But Actually the final output of this is string ["4565"] and what i actually need is to JSON encode of individual values in field ["45","65"]

Comment: What is the value in `$_POST['invite_id']` before passing in this PHP statement?

Comment: Using Ajax before posting  to PHP value is appending to that field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seperate the values by a comma in your js:

```
$('#invite_id').val($('#invite_id').val()+','+ui.item.friend_id);
```

then explode on the comma in php to create the array:

```
(isset($_POST['invite_id']))?json_encode(explode(',',$_POST['invite_id'])):json_encode(NULL);
```

Answer (score 0):

on the PHP side I expect you'll want to do an 'explode' on the $_POST['invide_id'] to get an array of elements.  $_POST['BLAH'] will only return a string.

e.g. something like...

```
$_POST['invite_id']=(isset($_POST['invite_id']))?json_encode(explode($_POST[',', 'invite_id']))):json_encode(NULL);
```